# Child component only rendering last object from Parent map method inside a Table, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, key, parent-child

I have a table on Parent component which is rendering data(Wallets) from firestore using map function for rows in table. Then I'm making child component for modal to update the data onClick of table row using button.

**The issue is: I only able to see the last object from data(Wallets) when click on the table row button regardless of clicking in any row of table.** I thought the issue was because of Key but even after adding key in Parent component still the same.

Need help to understand what is the issue here?

**Parent component (Wallets.js)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Wallets.css'
import { collection, updateDoc, deleteDoc, addDoc, getDoc, getDocs, query, onSnapshot, doc, limit, orderBy, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from '../../../Firebase';
import { CTable, CButton, CTableHead, CTableRow, CTableHeaderCell, CTableBody, CTableDataCell } from '@coreui/react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ModalWallets from '../ModalWallets/ModalWallets';

function Wallets() {

const [wallets, setWallets] = useState([])
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
const [modalValue, setModalValue] = useState(false);



// console.log(wallets, 'wallets')


const handleAddRemove = () => {

    console.log('calicked handleAddRemove')
    setModalValue(true)

}

const handleClickEditClose = (value) => {

    setModalValue(value)

}



useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'Wallets'));
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        setWallets(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
            {
                uid: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
            }
        )))
    });
}, [])

return (
    <div className='Wallets'>
        <div className='wallets__main'>
            <div className='wallets__table__admin'>
                <CTable striped hover>
                    <CTableHead>
                        <CTableRow>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">No.</CTableHeaderCell>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Name</CTableHeaderCell>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Email</CTableHeaderCell>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Role</CTableHeaderCell>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Balance</CTableHeaderCell>
                            <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Action</CTableHeaderCell>

                        </CTableRow>
                    </CTableHead>
                    <CTableBody>
                        {wallets && wallets.map((item, index) => {
                            item.serial = index + 1;

                            return <CTableRow key={index}>
                                <CTableHeaderCell scope="row">{item.serial}</CTableHeaderCell>
                                <CTableDataCell>{item.data.name}</CTableDataCell>
                                <CTableDataCell>{item.data.email}</CTableDataCell>
                                <CTableDataCell>{item.data.role}</CTableDataCell>
                                <CTableDataCell>${" "}{item.data.balance}</CTableDataCell>
                                <CTableDataCell>
                                    <CButton
                                        onClick={handleAddRemove}
                                    >
                                        Add Amount
                                    </CButton>

                                </CTableDataCell>
                            </CTableRow>
                        })}
                    </CTableBody>
                </CTable>
                {wallets && wallets.map((item, index) => {
                    return <ModalWallets
                        modalValue={modalValue}
                        handleClickEditClose={handleClickEditClose}
                        Email={item.data.email}
                        Role={item.data.role}
                        Balance={item.data.balance}
                        Name={item.data.name}
                        id={item.uid}
                        key={item.uid}
                    />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
)
}

export default Wallets
```

**Child component (Modal Wallets)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './ModalWallets.css'
import { Alert, CButton, CModal, CModalHeader, CModalTitle, CModalBody } from '@coreui/react';
import { doc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from '../../../Firebase';





function ModalWallets({ modalValue, handleClickEditClose, Email, Role, Balance, Name, id }) {


console.log(id, 'id ')
console.log(Email, "email", id, 'id, ')


const [balanceState, setBalanceState] = useState(0);


const handleUpdate = async (id) => {

    console.log(id, 'id in handleUpdate')

    const updateQuery = doc(db, 'Wallets', id);

    // console.log(updateQuery, 'updateQuery is run')
    try {
        await updateDoc(updateQuery, {
            balance: balanceState,
        }).then((response) => {
            alert('Updated balance succesfully')
        }).then((response) => {
            handleClickEditClose(false)
        })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(err, 'err in balance')
            })
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err, 'Error updating balance')
    }
}



useEffect(() => {
    setBalanceState(Balance)

}, [])


return (
    <div className='ModalWallets'>
        <CModal style={{ opacity: '0px' }} alignment='center' backdrop={true} size="xl" visible={modalValue} onClose={() => handleClickEditClose(false)}>
            <CModalHeader>
                <CModalTitle>Add/Remove Balance</CModalTitle>
            </CModalHeader>
            <CModalBody>
                <div className='body__modalwallet'>
                    <div className='body__col__left'>
                        <h2>Name</h2>
                        <h2>Email</h2>
                        <h2>{" "}Balance</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className='body__col__left'>
                        <h2>{Name}</h2>
                        <h2>{Email}</h2>
                        ${" "}<input
                            id={id}
                            type='number'
                            value={balanceState}
                            onChange={e => setBalanceState(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='modal__button' style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <button style={{ display: 'block', marginTop: '50px', width: '140px', height: '35px' }}
                        onClick={() => handleUpdate(id)}
                    >update</button>
                    <button style={{ display: 'block', marginTop: '50px', width: '140px', height: '35px' }} >Delete</button>
                </div>
            </CModalBody>
        </CModal>
    </div>
)
}

export default ModalWallets
```

***Parent Component (Table with rendering data and button to tigger child component Modal)***

[Parent Component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sEIN.png)

***Child component with clicking on first row of table email:walletUser@gmail.com but showing row third (the issue)***

[Child component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjmhC.png)

Comment: Looks like you're opening all modals, they're just layered on top of each other. This is because you have one `modalValue` state, that is either true (show) or false (hide), but it doesn't state anything about which modal should be displayed. When you set it to true, all modals are shown (just layered I think). You could instead make `modalValue` hold an id of which modal should be visible

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, that was the problem indeed. So to solve this i need to pass the id to child and again call my data(wallet) and make conditional statement if id passed equlas to id in data (wallet). Would that be the approach?

Comment: @NickParsons, that way i need to call my data(wallet) 2 times. thus performance issue!

Comment: Yes, that would be the approach. Not really sure what you mean by you would need to call data (wallet) twice though. The performance should be the same as what you currently have.